# Script to create environment variable

Tags: bash

I want to create a script that will create an environment  variable  that will hold a folder name called "templates". After I create the global variable with the script , I would be able to get to the path of the folder name automatically   on the command line, without  typing  the path again and again.

Can you please suggest ideas.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: unclear what you're asking. Can you show us what you want to type at the command line?

Comment: what's unclear about it?

Answer (score 1):

use `export` for this.

example:

```
echo "export T=templates" > setvar
. setvar
```

usage:

```
cd $T
```